# How to start microvm with LUKS encrypted file system(rootfs.ext4) using firecracker?

Tags: firecracker

I have created an encrypted filesystem(rootfs.ext4) using LUKS. Trying to start microvm by using LUKS encrypted file system with firecracker.

Is it possible to start microvm with encrypted file system..? Can anyone suggest on this.